# htaccess url rewrite for pretty url not working on Apache localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to apply "pretty" URLs to my website.

ie: `localhost/api/?id=15`

to

```
localhost/api/id/15
```

here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteRule ^/?id/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Nothing seems to be working but htaccess looks fine here.

Do I need to update any apache configuration?

Comment: This solution is different from what you have asked, but it will give you better management over such pretty url's. [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I want to do this with .htacces .@Abhishek

Comment: Where is your htaccess file? In the document root?

Comment: .htaccess location /var/www/html/api  @JonLin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This htaccess looks fine. htaccess override and apache rewrite module was not enabled.
I had to edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

to enable apache rewrite module .

and finally restart apache using sudo `service apache2 restart` to see the changes in action .

Comment: Getting 500 internal server error after doing this....

Answer (score 0):

As @Abhishek mentioned in the comments, you can use [AltoRouter.](http://www.altorouter.com) No point reinventing the wheel if it exists and works well.

```
require 'AltoRouter.php';
$r = new AltoRouter();
$r->map('/api/id/[i:id]', function($userid) {
    // your logic for what this URL does
    // [i:id] will look for any integers and store it as $userid
}, 'example');
$m = $r->match();
if($m && is_callable($m['target'])):
    call_user_func_array($m['target'], $m['params']);
else:
    header('Location: /404');
    exit();
```

You'll find documentation on the site and example htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

For urls like this

```
localhost/api/id/15
```

the htaccess can be like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteRule ^id/([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In `id=$1` you will get `id=15`

Comment: I found what was causing the problem. htaccess override and apache rewrite module was not enabled .  My htaccess file is fine , it is working now .

Comment: then, you can safetly delete the question as it will not useful for somebody else

Comment: I have updated the question , hope this will be helpful for others who is facing the same problem.